# Paginamento de paginas php

Tags: php, paginação

ola estou criando um sistema de pesquisa e preciso criar um paginamento pensei em usar `$_SESSION`porem notei que daria erro segue a baixo o codigo q desenvolvi ate agora

Pesquisa:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['PG'])){
    if(isset($_SESSION['pg'])){

        $id=$numpg-$_SESSION['pg'];

    }else{
        $_GET['PG']=0;
    }
}else{
    $_GET['PG']=0;
}
if(is_numeric($_GET['PG'])){
?>
<div class="corpo container">
<?php
$i=0;
?>
<div class="row">
<?php
    $ps=$_GET['PS'];
    $sql="SELECT id FROM indexes WHERE (modo!=4 and nome LIKE '%$ps%') ORDER BY id DESC";
    $exe=mysqli_query($link,$sql);
    $numrow=mysqli_num_rows($exe);
    if($_GET['PG']==0){
        $sql="SELECT nome,foto,vew,tkm,modo,id FROM indexes WHERE (modo!=4 and nome LIKE '%$ps%') ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 12";
    }else{
        $sql="SELECT nome,foto,vew,tkm,modo,id FROM indexes WHERE (modo!=4 and nome LIKE '%$ps%') and (id <= $id) ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 12";
    }
    $exe=mysqli_query($link,$sql);
    //echo e($numrow);
    while($row=MYSQLI_FETCH_ARRAY($exe)){
        $nome=$row['nome'];
        $foto=$row['foto'];
        $vew=$row['vew'];
        $tkm=$row['tkm'];
        $modo=$row['modo'];
        $pxid= $row['id'];

        $i++;

?>




<div class="col-md-3 sb-preview text-center">
<div class="card h-100">
<div id="vew">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span>: <?php echo e($vew); ?>
</div>
<a class="sb-preview-img" href="<?php ?>">
<img class="card-img-top" src="../_img/<?php echo e($foto) ?>"    style="width:100%;">
</a>

<div class="card-body">

<h3 class="card-title">
<?php echo e($nome) ?> 
<?php if($modo == 1){ ?> 
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-film"></span>
<?php }else if($modo == 2){?>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-camera"></span>
<?php }else{ ?>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-header"></span>
<?php } ?>
</h3>
</div>
</div>
</div>



<?php
if($i==4){
?>
</div>
<?php
$i=0;
?>
<div class="row">

<?php
}
if($numrow>12){
 $_SESSION['pg']=$pxid;
}
}
?>
<?php
if($numrow>12){
    if($i>0 and $i<4 ){
      ?>  
      </div>
      <?php
    }
?>

<div class="row">
<nav class="text-center">
  <ul class="pagination pagination-sm">
  <?php
    $pg=$numrow/12;
    $pg = ceil($pg);
    //echo $pg;
    for($i=1;$pg>=$i;$i++){
    if($i==1){
  ?>
    <li><a href="?PS=<?php echo e($_GET['PS']) ?>&PG=0">1</a></li>
    <?php
    }else{
    ?>
    <li><a href="?PS=<?php echo e($_GET['PS']) ?>&PG=<?php echo e($i)?>"><?php echo e($i)?></a></li>    
    <?php
    }
    }
    ?>
  </ul>
</nav>
</div>
<?php 
}
?>
</div>
<?php

}else{

}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encontrei alguns artigos e vídeos exatamente com sua duvidas, veja se isso te esclarece:

[Sistema de Paginação de Resultados usando Bootstrap, PHP e MySQL](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hPsYf0BeHKk) - Canal: [**Zero Bugs**](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC6BN1oSRAxcABupjn_bnT7g)

[Como fazer paginação PHP e MySQLi?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KvzqN6iSaSw) - Canal: [**Celke - PHP**](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC5ClMRHFl8o_MAaO4w7ZYug)

[Como fazer Paginação em PHP com MySQL](https://www.devmedia.com.br/paginacao-em-php/21972) - [DevMedia](https://www.devmedia.com.br/)

Bom espero que estes Vídeos e Artigo te ajudem assim como me ajudaram a realizar a paginação.